# Show variable outside while loop

Tags: while-loop

Hy. I know there are answers similar, but i can't get it going. Here is my cod:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'connect.php';

$q = mysqli_query($link, $aaa = 'SELECT * FROM agentii LEFT JOIN orase ON agentii.oras=orase.oras_id WHERE orase.oras_id = \'' .$_GET['id']. '\'') or die(mysqli_error($link));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
?>

<h2>Title <em><?php echo $row['oras'];?></em></h2>

<div class="div_view">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Agentie</th>
            <th>Adresa</th>
        </tr>

        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['agentie'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['adresa'];?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php }?>

    </table>
</div>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

This output(i can't put images because is a new account - so i put a link to a prt src):
http://postimage.org/image/w9zsexz91/

In my database i have 3 rows, and the code outputs only 2.
I know that is because of the 2 mysqli_fetch_assoc, but i want to show all the rows, and i want to show the title too (`<?php echo $row['oras'];?>`) outside the while.

Can someone please help me with this?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obligatory **warning** first: Remember little [Bobby Tables!](http://bobby-tables.com/) 
(or: your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks)

then: you get only two rows in the while loop, because you requested a row outside the loop first, thus increasing the internal cursor in the result.

If you want to get title and rows in one go, you need to cache the result, for example:

```
$resultArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
  $resultArray[] = $row;
}
//....
?>
<h2><?php echo $resultArray[0]['oras']; ?></h2>

<?php // ... ?>

<?php foreach($resultArray as $row) {
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentie'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['adresa'];?></td>
  </tr>
} ?>
```

this is just a stub, of course you should implement checks if you got a row at all etc...

Comment: Yes! This works. Thx man! Both answer are good, but i will stick with yours answer - it make more sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php do { ?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['agentie'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['adresa'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)); ?>
```

The first iteration of this loop will print the first fetched row. I have only changed the location of the `while` clause, forcing the code of the loop to be run before a new row is fetched.